# Using history.pushState to put an additional page into smoothState.js history doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, smoothstate.js

How would I put a dynamic page created with Ajax to the **smootState.js** history. I've tried using `history.pushState()` but that didn't seem to work. For example, with an anchor you land on a page named `Projects.html`. From that page on you do an ajax call and insert new content into a div and use `history.pushState()` to change the url to `Projects.html?id=1`. This page is also fully recreated if you do a refresh, but if you navigate somewhere else and trying coming back to this page it throws an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined`.

This is the part from the smoothState.js plugin to where I am trying to "plug-in".

```html
 /** Handles the popstate event, like when the user hits 'back' */
    onPopState = function ( e ) {
      if(e.state !== null) {
        var url = window.location.href,
          $page = $('#' + e.state.id),
          page = $page.data('smoothState'),
          diffUrl = (page.href !== url && !utility.isHash(url, page.href)),
          diffState = (e.state !== page.cache[page.href].state);

        if(diffUrl || diffState) {
          if (diffState) {
            page.clear(page.href);
          }
          page.load(url, false);
        }
      }
    },
```

and this is how it stores the history object.

```html
var destUrl = cache[settings.url].destUrl;

/** Prepare a history entry */
state = options.alterChangeState({ id: elementId }, cache[settings.url].title, destUrl);

/** Update the cache to include the history entry for future comparisons */
cache[settings.url].state = state;

/** Add history entry */
window.history.pushState(state, cache[settings.url].title, destUrl);
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) tried with this? its simpler

Comment: @Luminous_Dev Why? Could you please elaborate a little. What can I do with history.js that can't be done with the native History API and what would it help with this example?

Comment: history.js first of all supports most of the browsers, less code to write. And I think, you need to add the content data on the state when you push and rebind the view with that data you stored within that state when you come back to it

Comment: Hi there, I'm doing exactly the same thing, did you ever find a solution? Cheers